My VR avatar in blender have white around eyebrows and eyelashes. Fix?
I am new to Blender so any answer you give Please explain it to me. The problem that I am facing is when I import my avatar head, the lashes, and the eyebrows are filled with a thick white border that I can't get rid of. I was in the middle of a YouTube video but the creator doesn't seem to be active as much anymore. So I retried everything from scratch 4 times without skipping a second of the video but nothing would help me get rid of those lines. a few people were having the same problem but I can't find anyone or anything talking about the same exact issue as me. Here is the avatar down below so that you can see what I mean ((edit: oh apologies here is the video))
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDLOhAgrZTM&t=1284s

Here is my setup so far







Looks like it's because you're in Solid view mode with the Texture overlay enabled. Those are supposed to be alpha textures that make that geo transparent where it's black and opaque where white. Try switching to Rendered view mode (Z) and see if that fixes it.

It would help if you'd added a link to the YT video you were following into your question otherwise we can only guess what the creator was doing! You can edit your question and add the link into it.

@Jakemoyo i tried to press z but still nothing, it looks horrifying though :')

@JohnEason apologies, i added a link, im using the same head as her as well

Well, the video clearly says, plug the Color into the Alpha. Have you done that? It would really help if you show your material setup as well. In the video there's two images, one for the Base Color, one for the Alpha. Have you confused those two and plugged them the other way around?

@GordonBrinkmann everything is the same as hers, I plugged it into the color and it turns the head into that:C I made sure I checked the other plugins to be sure it was matching hers. I restarted from scratch 6 times to be sure

But even if for example you have not set the Blend Mode correctly so that the transparency could not work in EEVEE, there still is a difference in your brows and lashes being white in the assumed opaque areas while in the video they are black. So either you did something wrong (but as long as you will not provide further information which you seem to think is unnecessary, I won't keep on guessing blindly) or this is not a beginner tutorial and there are parts left out which they expect experienced users to figure out on their own which is why your setup doesn't work.

@GordonBrinkmann Very sorry, i updated the post. unfortunately i can only upload 7 images at the time

I believe I know what is causing this.
I was watching the same video and of course she left out an important step to those who don't use Blender.
Above where she clicked Fix Model there are little circles. (They are called view modes as Jake was saying) - you can also select the background of your avatar and click Z to get all the view mode options there.

One is grid looking, one is solid and another is quarter and then even less than that.
You'll want to select the quarter filled in one or less Material Preview Rendered.
You'll want to go to the face mesh- if you watch the video linked it's at the step when you are adding the face textures/eye textures.
Scroll all the way down to Alpha Blend, like you did for the lashes and change the blend mode from Alpha Blend to Opaque.
